# Partitions of n that generate all numbers smaller than n

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Consider a  partition $$n=n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k$$ such that each  number $1,\cdots, n$ can be obtained
by adding some of the numbers  $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k$. 
For example, $$9=4+3+1+1,$$

and every number $1,2,\cdots,9$ be ca written as a sum of some of the numbers $4,3,1,1$. This other  partition 
 $$9=6+1+1+1$$ 
fails the desired property, as $4$ (and $5$)  cannot be given by any sum of $6,1,1,1$.

**Question:** Can we charaterize which partitions of an arbitrary $n$ have
this property? We clearly need at least one $1$ among $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k$,
and intuitively we need  many small numbers $n_i$. But I can't see much beyond this. Any idea or reference  will be appreciated.

Comment: If at least half of the number are 1's, you can do it. But the condition is certainly not necessary.

Comment: I once studied this problem and found a constructive partition method. Here is the brief. We are given a positive integer $n$. STEP ONE: if $n$ is an even number, partition it into $A=\frac{n}{2}$ and $B=\frac{n}{2}$; otherwise, partition it into $A=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and $B=\frac{n-1}{2}$. STEP TWO: re-partition $B$ into $A_1$ and $B_1$. STEP THREE: re-partition $B_1$......Until we get $1$. I didn't prove this method always works but I believe it is valid.

Comment: EXAMPLE: $13 \rightarrow (7,6) \rightarrow (7,3,3) \rightarrow (7,3,2,1)$. May it be helpful.

Comment: @apprenant. This method looks interesting. BTW, is this problem well known?

Comment: You can work up the other way, too, by powers of two, e.g $13 \to 1,2,4,6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be a partition of $n$. The required condition is that $\lambda$ contain partitions $\lambda_i$ of each $1 \le i < n$. Clearly if $\lambda$ contains a partition of $j$ then it also contains a partition of $(n - j)$, being the multiset difference $\lambda - \lambda_j$.

Therefore the first thing to notice is that $\lambda$ cannot contain any element $a > \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$, for if it did then $\{a\}$ cannot be part of a partition of $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ and $\lambda - \{a\}$ is a partition of $(n - a) < (n - \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil) < \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ cannot contain a partition of $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$.

Now, suppose that the largest element of $\lambda$ is $m$. It is certainly *sufficient* that $\lambda - \{m\}$ should satisfy the corresponding condition of providing partitions for each $1 \le i < (n - m)$. Proof: $\lambda - \{m\}$ is a partition of $(n - m)$ and provides partitions for each smaller natural number, so it remains to construct partitions $\lambda_i$ for $(n - m) < i < n$. We can do this by taking partitions from $\lambda - \{m\}$ for $(n - 2m) < j < n - m$ and then adding $\{m\}$ to each one. This can only fail if $j < 0$, which can only happen if $(n - 2m) < -1$. Since $m \le \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ we have $n - 2m \ge n - 2\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$, which is $0$ if $n$ is even and $-1$ if $n$ is odd, so all cases are covered.

The interesting question is whether it's *necessary* that $\lambda - \{m\}$ should satisfy the same condition. Clearly it must contain partitions of $1 \le i < m$, since $\{m\}$ doesn't participate in them. And by the simple principle of taking complements in $\lambda$ it's clear that for each $m \le i < n$ the remnant $\lambda - \{m\}$ must either contain partitions of $(i - m)$ and $n - i$; or $i$ and $n - m - i$. Is that sufficient?

My intuition is that it's necessary, and testing on small examples (up to $n = 30$) supports that, but I haven't proved it.

In the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences it's [A126796](https://oeis.org/A126796) and a comment claims the characterisation

> A partition is complete iff each part is no more than 1 more than the sum of all smaller parts. (This includes the smallest part, which thus must be 1.) - Franklin T. Adams-Watters, Mar 22 2007

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick and dirty list of the first examples, for $n$ up to $10$.  Feel free to edit, extend, or amend.

$$1\\1+1\\
1+1+1\quad1+2\\
1+1+1+1\quad1+1+2\\
1^5\quad1+1+1+2\quad1+2+2\quad1+1+3\\
1^6\quad1^4+2\quad1^2+2+2\quad1^3+3\quad1+2+3\\
1^7\quad1^5+2\quad1^3+2+2\quad1+2^3\quad1^4+3\quad1^2+2+3\quad1^3+4\quad1+2+4\\
1^8\quad1^6+2\quad1^4+2+2\quad1^2+2+2+2\quad1^5+3\quad1^3+2+3\quad1^2+3+3\quad1+2+2+3\quad1^4+4\quad1+1+2+4\\
1^9\quad1^7+2\quad1^5+2+2\quad1^3+2^3\quad1+2^4\quad1^6+3\quad1^4+2+3\quad1^2+2+2+3\quad1^3+3+3\quad1+2+3+3\quad1^5+4\quad1^3+2+4\quad1+2+2+4\quad1+1+3+4\quad1^4+5\quad1^2+2+5\\
1^{10}\quad1^8+2\quad1^6+2^2\quad1^4+2^3\quad1^2+2^4\quad1^7+3\quad1^5+2+3\quad1^3+2^2+3\quad1+2^3+3\quad1^4+3^2\quad1^2+2+3^2\quad1^6+4\quad1^4+2+4\quad1^2+2^2+4\quad1^3+3+4\quad1+2+3+4\quad1^5+5\quad1^3+2+5\quad1+2^2+5\quad1+1+3+5$$

I hope the meaning of the superscript notation is clear, and I hope someone will check that I didn't make any mistakes or overlook anything.  The list so far gives the sequence

$$1,1,2,2,4,5,8,10,16,20,\ldots$$

which (after correcting a pair of mistakes in the original posting here) Peter Taylor found in the OEIS.

Comment: I get 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 31, 39, 55, 71, 100, 125, 173, 218, 291 starting at index 0. [A126796](https://oeis.org/A126796)

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you! I see now what I missed: $7=1^3+4$ and $10=1+1+3+5$. Darn! I swear, I checked and double checked all my counts. I guess I needed to triple check....